# How to pass SSL processing from local NginX to Docker NginX?

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy

there. I have a docker nginx reverse proxy configured with ssl by configuration like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;


    # some locations location ... { ... }
}
```

The certificates are configured with certbot and working pretty fine.
All the containers are up and running. But I have multiple websites running on my server. They are managed by local NginX. So I set ports for the docker NginX like this:

```
nginx:
    image: example/example_nginx:latest
    container_name: example_nginx
    ports:
      - "8123:80"
      - "8122:443"
    volumes:
      - ${PROJECT_ROOT}/data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ${PROJECT_ROOT}/data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
```

The docker port 80 maps to local port 8123 (http). The docker port 443 maps to local port 8122 (https). To pass the request from local NginX to docker container NginX I use the following config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  location / {
      access_log off;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8123;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
      access_log off;
      proxy_pass https://localhost:8122;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

When I open the website it works but certificate seems to be broken and my WebSockets crash.

[image]

My question is: how can I pass ssl processing from local NginX to docker NginX so that it will work as expected?
~
~
~

Comment: Do you have an automatic HTTP -> HTTPS redirect? If the answer is no, then what happens if you put the https:// into the browser address bar manually?

Comment: It works the same way as with HTTP -> HTTPS redirect.